# JavaScript NaN error, input text displays as NaN

Tags: javascript

When I create a text input form and I write some name in it, the code sees my input as a number, and when I output it, i have an error (NaN), somewhere I am doing something wrong help me please... THX

```
<h1>Please enter your name</h1>
     <input id="nameid" type="text">

var nameUser = document.getElementById("nameid");
        var name = nameUser.toString();

document.write('<h2>' +'Worker name:\t'+ +name+ '<\h2>');
```

Here is the entire code i am working with.

```
    <script>

      function doStuff()
      {

        var nameAge = document.getElementById("ageInput");
        var age = parseInt(nameAge.value);
        var nameSalary = document.getElementById("salaryInput");
        var salary = parseFloat(nameSalary.value);
        var nameUser = document.getElementById("nameid");
        var name = nameUser.toString();




                document.write('<h2>' +'Age experience:\t'+ +age+ '<\h2>');
                document.write('<h2>' +'Worker name:\t'+ +name+ '<\h2>');
                document.write('<h2>' +'Starting salary ($):\t'+ +salary+ '<\h2>');

                 if (age>=3 && age<10) {
                            var increase_1;
                            var salary_2;
                            increase_1=(salary*10)/100;
                            salary_2=salary+increase_1;

                            document.write('<h4>'  +'Proceeding from work experience the new salary was increase by 10%:\t'+ +salary_2+  '<\h4>');
                        }      
                else if (age>=10 && age<20){
                            var increase_2;
                            var salary_3;
                            increase_2=(salary*25)/100;
                            salary_3=salary+increase_2;
                            document.write('<h4>' +'Proceeding from work experience the new salary was increase by 25%:\t'+ +salary_3+  '<\h4>');
                }
                else if (age>=20){

                            document.write('<h4>' +'Proceeding from work experience you get a prize:'+  '<\h4>');
                            document.write('<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2T_AGEs19_4/T_c2ERHsJeI/AAAAAAAIK9E/MGAQAa9ppDE/s800/2013-Mercedes-G-Class-AMG-011.jpg">');
                        }
                 else  {
                            document.write('<h4>' +'Proceeding from work experience the  salary is:\t' +salary+'<\h4>');

                        }                                   

      }
    </script>
    <h1>Please enter your work experience(years)</h1>
     <input id="ageInput" type="number">
    <h1>Please enter your salary($)</h1>
     <input id="salaryInput" type="number">
   <h1>Please enter your name</h1>
     <input id="nameid" type="text"> 
     <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="doStuff()">


</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using double `+`? for example here: `'<h2>' +'Worker name:\t'+ +name+ '<\h2>'`

Comment: Why are you converting name to numeric?

Comment: ...after just having it made a string a few lines above, explicitly with toString()... and now, where you need a string, you convert to Number with the + prefix.

Comment: To clarify the previous comments, the ***unary plus*** operator converts its operand to a numeric value. For example, `+"50"` yields the numeric result `50`. If the operand cannot be sensibly converted to a number (e.g., `+"foo"`) the result is `NaN`.

Comment: ... which is useless since age and salary already ARE Number, and "name" see comments above. Looks like someone is REALLY confused about types and misuses Javascript's loose type system to the fullest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
    var nameUser = document.getElementById("nameid");
    var name = nameUser.toString();
```

You need to get the value.  Change to:

```
    var nameUser = document.getElementById("nameid");
    var name = nameUser.value.toString();
```

Then change:

```
    document.write('<h2>' +'Worker name:\t'+ +name+ '<\h2>');
```

to:

```
    document.write('<h2>' +'Worker name:\t' +name+ '<\h2>');
```

should be good.  See http://jsfiddle.net/h6zPv/ for the full code